# Xcode Asset Catalog not showing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I’m a new developer to Xcode and I’m trying to create my first app. However when I want to add to my asset catalog, I’m not finding the import button or when I drag and drop a image , it’s not going into a folder nor can I find a way to create a folder. I just have this blank empty space.

This is what a normal asset catalog looks like in YT tutorials:

[image]

This is what I get:
[image]

I tried looking into view, I’ve seen an Apple dev link that didn’t really help. It called for File>New> Asset catalog but it just creates this image icon as seen in my screenshot

Comment: I appreciate the grammar tip, but I would appreciate some actual help even more.

Comment: I notice that assets is called assets.xcassets on my projects. When selected at the bottom left corner there are +,- and filter buttons. Try renaming yours or adding a new one with the full name.

Answer (score 3):

you enabled code review, try disabling it
[image]